# Showing Websocket Data in HTML Page

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I am a beginner in Python and i am working in a small project using python Flask. The Task is taking Pulling websocket data from a server and showing those real time data back in the HTML Page.

So here is my main.py code,

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
import websockets
import asyncio
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/success/<wssAddress>')
def success(wssAddress):

    async with websockets.connect(wssAddress, ping_timeout=None) as ws:
        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            json_str = json.dumps(msg, indent=4)
    return 'Testing Websocket Address : %s' % json_str
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(success())

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        addressAccum = request.form['wssAddress']
        return redirect(url_for('success', wssAddress=addressAccum))
    else:
        addressAccum = request.args.get('nm')
        return redirect(url_for('success', wssAddress=addressAccum))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here is my HTML Code that contains form to input the WSS server address,

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/login" method = "post">

        <p>Enter WSS Address:</p>

        <p><input type = "text" name = "wssAddress" /></p>
        <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

my intentional output would be,

Testing Websocket Address : wss://testing.data
{
"x":"1381974" , "y" : "3211241241"
"x":"1381974" , "y" : "3211241241"
"x":"1381974" , "y" : "3211241241"

```
And so on...
```

}

i know this is some beginner question but i really appreciate if someone could help me with my issue.
Thank you so much.

Here is the input form HTML Page,

[image]

and this is the result

[image]